# Convert Java Object to JsonNode in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to directly convert a Java Object to an JsonNode-Object?

The only way I found to solve this is to convert the Java Object to String and then to JsonNode:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653996/how-to-parse-a-json-string-into-jsonnode-in-jackson) may be helpful.

Comment: @PLB unfortunately not. I don't want to create a JSON-String. I want to directly convert a Java-Object to a JsonNode-Object

Answer (score 399, accepted):

As of Jackson 1.6, you can use:

```
JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(map);
```

or

```
JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(object, JsonNode.class);
```

Source: [is there a way to serialize pojo's directly to treemodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967583/jackson-is-there-a-way-to-serialize-pojos-directly-to-treemodel)

Comment: It appears that ObjectMapper.valueToTree wasn't added until Jackson 1.6, so the alternative is great for those of us that haven't upgraded yet!

Comment: It is funny that valueToTree is implemented like write and read: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L2542 :D

Comment: Useful to know that the other way is also possible: there's a treeToValue method as well.

Comment: You can also use `ObjectNode node = mapper.convertValue(myObject, ObjectNode.class)` to convert directly to ObjectNode

Comment: I am trying to convert a java class into JsonNode. But getting nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an array ....  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
     JsonNode jsonInput = mapper.convertValue(myJavaClass, JsonNode.class); Using  Jackson-databind-2.11.0