# Convert JsonNode object to Map

Tags: java, json, jackson, playframework-2.2

I have a C# program that sends me a json object.
I'm making a Java Play website to capture the POST data.
I get the correct data as a `JsonNode` object but need to convert it into a `Map`.

I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`

Here is where I correctly capture the JsonNode object:

```
public static Result index() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
}
```

Now that I have the object I need to figure out how to convert it into a `Map` so that I can so some magic on it. Later I'll want to convert the `Map` back into a json object to be sent in the response.

I've been looking in the documentation, but the methods available don't scream as the solution.

Here is the documentation I've been referencing for this particular `JsonNode` object:
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Got here trying to find the answer myself. Dug a little deeper and found a bit the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828368/convert-java-object-to-jsonnode-in-jackson)

Basically just use the `ObjectMapper` to convert the value for you:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

Comment: Correction, it is Map<String, Object> by the way. The value can be String, Integer,..

Comment: You may wish to write Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){}); to avoid warning of unchecked assignment from Map to Map<String, Object>.