# How to convert HashMap to JsonNode with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `HashMap` object which I want to convert to `JsonNode` tree using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. What is the best way to do it?

I found the following code but since I don't know the Jackson API well, I wonder if there are some better ways.

```java
mapper.reader().readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(hashmap))
```

Comment: What do you need the JsonNode instance for that a Hashmap can't achieve?

Comment: I think you should for loop and manual convert it :)... some think was wrong when you try convert by auto function because your object maybe not correctly with function required,,

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```java
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.convertValue(map, JsonNode.class);
```

Or use the *more elegant* solution pointed in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391095/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-jsonnode-with-jackson/39393002#comment75755795_39393002):

```java
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(map);
```

---

If you need to write your `jsonNode` as a string, use:

```java
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
```

Comment: This answer is a little more elegant IMHO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828368/convert-java-object-to-jsonnode-in-jackson

Answer (score 5):

First transform your map in a JsonNode :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNodeMap = mapper.convertValue(myMap, JsonNode.class);
```

Then add this node to your ObjectNode with the set method :

```
myObjectNode.set("myMapName", jsonNodeMap);
```

To convert from JsonNode to ObjectNode use :

```
ObjectNode myObjectNode = (ObjectNode) myJsonNode;
```

Comment: How is it different from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39393002/1426227)?