# Converting mapdifference to jsonnode

Tags: java, guava, jsonnode

I am comparing two json document and is using mapdifference to get the difference of the two.
Now i want to patch this difference to an existing json, but the difference returned is in the form

```
/applicant/0/EmployDetail/0/AnnualSalary: 99999868.99
/Notes/0/customNote: OM Application Notes
```

and so on.

Used the following to generate the difference:

```
MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(leftFlatMap, rightFlatMap);
difference.entriesOnlyOnRight().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
```

I am expecting it to convert it to a jsonnode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HashMap to JsonNode with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391095/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-jsonnode-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonNode jsonDifference = new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(difference.entriesOnlyOnRight());
```