# Java : Convert Java Object into JacksonJsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

Java : How to convert :

From
Object String(java.lang.Object) :

```
String [{"rule_id":7528,"name":"JAY_TEST_RULE"}]
```

To
JsonNode(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode):

```
{"rule_id":7528,"name":"JAY_TEST_RULE"} 


My Attempts :

Using 

Object actionInfoValue = memcachedObject.getDataForKey(actionInfoKey); 

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

actionInfo = mapper.convertValue(actionInfoValue,JsonNode.class);

OR 

actionInfo = mapper.valueToTree(actionInfoValue.toString());
```

I get

```
actionInfo = "[{\"rule_id\":7528,\"name\":\"JAY_TEST_RULE\"}]"
```

But I need

```
actionInfo = {"rule_id":7528,"name":"JAY_TEST_RULE"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Java Object to JsonNode in Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828368/convert-java-object-to-jsonnode-in-jackson)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson: is there a way to serialize POJOs directly to treemodel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967583/jackson-is-there-a-way-to-serialize-pojos-directly-to-treemodel)

Comment: Your object is an array, you can convert it to JsonArray

Comment: I had checked ur links before.. it gives me escaped jsonArray instead on JsonNode.. please check updated question again. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

> String actionInfoValue = (String) memcachedObject.getDataForKey(actionInfoKey);

Above will give me Array of JsonString , to convert it to JsonString i used substring method as below.

> actionInfoValue = actionInfoValue.substring( 1 , actionInfoValue.length() - 1);