# how to convert json to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in java like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(jsonstr) in c#

Tags: java, json, arraylist, json-deserialization

How to convert json to ArrayList<ArrayList> in java.

Corresponding c# code using NewtonJson is like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Object>>>(jsonstr)
```

But what would it be in Java? I could not find package for this.
If target type were some class then it would be easy using gson. But my problem is target type being double list ArrayList<ArrayList>.

Regards Orgil.D

Comment: I found a few answers, [Jackson: is there a way to serialize POJOs directly to treemodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967583/jackson-is-there-a-way-to-serialize-pojos-directly-to-treemodel), and [Convert Java Object to JsonNode in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828368/convert-java-object-to-jsonnode-in-jackson)